# Is it possible to add a where clause with list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, python-assignment-expression, python-3.8

Consider the following list comprehension

```
[ (x,f(x)) for x in iterable if f(x) ]
```

This filters the iterable based a condition `f` and returns the pairs of `x,f(x)`. The problem with this approach is `f(x)` is calculated twice.
It would be great if we could write like

```
[ (x,fx) for x in iterable if fx where fx = f(x) ]
or
[ (x,fx) for x in iterable if fx with f(x) as fx ]
```

But in python we have to write using nested comprehensions to avoid duplicate call to f(x) and it makes the comprehension look less clear

```
[ (x,fx) for x,fx in ( (y,f(y) for y in iterable ) if fx ]
```

Is there any other way to make it more pythonic and readable?

---

**Update**

Coming soon in python 3.8! [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics)

```
# Share a subexpression between a comprehension filter clause and its output
filtered_data = [y for x in data if (y := f(x)) is not None]
```

Comment: Are you *sure* it is calculated twice when you have compiled it?

Comment: Not sure how to compile. But on the python prompt, it is executed twice. I checked by adding a print statement.

Comment: If you don't want to compute `f(x)` twice, try to add a cache in `f()`.

Comment: @Vixen: yes, python will call `f(x)` twice for every `x in iterable` in the first statement.

Comment: @CédricJulien Yes. it is also one of the possible ways. But I am trying to find a cleaner way. Adding a cache will have a dictionary look-up and might be a overkill for simple lambdas.

Comment: this is not so much a "`[... where ...]` clause", so much as wanting to optimize the `[... if ...]` clause and/or to introduce `let`-style anonymous bindings.

Comment: @ninjagecko yes, `let` is exactly the term.

Comment: @balki Please move your "update" section from inside the question to a new answer. See [Should you put an answer to your own question and mark it as the accepted answer or update your question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271399) and [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267434) for an explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seek to have `let`-statement semantics in python list comprehensions, whose scope is available to both the `___ for..in`(map) and the `if ___`(filter) part of the comprehension, and whose scope depends on the `..for ___ in...`.

---

**Your solution, modified:**
Your (as you admit unreadable) solution of `[ (x,fx) for x,fx in ( (y,f(y) for y in iterable ) if fx ]` is the most straightforward way to write the optimization.

Main idea: lift x into the tuple (x,f(x)).

Some would argue the most "pythonic" way to do things would be the original `[(x,f(x)) for x in iterable if f(x)]` and accept the inefficiencies.

You can however factor out the `((y,fy) for y in iterable)` into a function, if you plan to do this a lot. This is bad because if you ever wish to have access to more variables than `x,fx` (e.g. `x,fx,ffx`), then you will need to rewrite all your list comprehensions. Therefore this isn't a great solution unless you know for sure you only need `x,fx` and plan to reuse this pattern.

---

**Generator expression:**

Main idea: use a more complicated alternative to generator expressions: one where python will let you write multiple lines.

You could just use a generator expression, which python plays nicely with:

```
def xfx(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        fx = f(x)
        if fx:
            yield (x,fx)

xfx(exampleIterable)
```

This is how I would personally do it.

---

**Memoization/caching:**

Main idea: You could also use(abuse?) side-effects and make `f` have a global memoization cache, so you don't repeat operations.

This can have a bit of overhead, and requires a policy of how large the cache should be and when it should be garbage-collected. Thus this should only be used if you'd have other uses for memoizing f, or if f is very expensive. But it would let you write...

```
[ (x,f(x)) for x in iterable if f(x) ]
```

...like you originally wanted without the performance hit of doing the expensive operations in `f` twice, even if you technically call it twice. You can add a `@memoized` decorator to `f`: [example](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) (without maximum cache size). This will work as long as x is hashable (e.g. a number, a tuple, a frozenset, etc.).

---

**Dummy values:**

Main idea: capture fx=f(x) in a closure and modify the behavior of the list comprehension.

```
filterTrue(
    (lambda fx=f(x): (x,fx) if fx else None)() for x in iterable
)
```

where filterTrue(iterable) is filter(None, iterable). You would have to modify this if your list type (a 2-tuple) was actually capable of being `None`.

Comment: Plus `xfx()` could be generalized by passing it the `f` function as an argument.

Answer (score 14):

There is no `where` statement but you can "emulate" it using `for`:

```
a=[0]
def f(x):
    a[0] += 1
    return 2*x

print [ (x, y) for x in range(5) for y in [f(x)] if y != 2 ]
print "The function was executed %s times" % a[0]
```

Execution:

```
$ python 2.py 
[(0, 0), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8)]
The function was executed 5 times
```

As you can see, the functions is executed 5 times, not 10 or 9.

This `for` construction:

```
for y in [f(x)]
```

imitate where clause.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing says you must use comprehensions. In fact most style guides I've seen request that you limit them to simple constructs, anyway.

You could use a generator expression, instead.

```
def fun(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        y = f(x)
        if y:
            yield x, y


print list(fun(iterable))
```

Answer (score 3):

Map and Zip ?

```
fnRes = map(f, iterable)
[(x,fx) for x,fx in zip(iterable, fnRes) if fx)]
```

Comment: `y==1` is extremely poor form; `y` is already a boolean, you could just say `if y` (rather than comparing True==1 / False==1; it's sort of like saying `return myBoolean==bool(1)`, which is worse than `return myBoolean==True`, rather than the usual `return myBoolean`). `y` could also be named something semantically meaningful, such as `fx`. Other than that, this is a reasonable answer. [edit: +1 =)]

Comment: Will not work if the iterable is a generator. Will have to use `itertools.tee` to get two iterators.

Comment: @balki Good point, also this could be inefficient in some cases.