# Is there a Python equivalent of the Haskell 'let'

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming, let

Is there a Python equivalent of the Haskell 'let' expression that would allow me to write something like:

```
list2 = [let (name,size)=lookup(productId) in (barcode(productId),metric(size)) 
            for productId in list]
```

If not, what would be the **most readable** alternative?

Added for clarification of the let syntax:

```
x = let (name,size)=lookup(productId) in (barcode(productId),metric(size))
```

is equivalent to

```
(name,size) = lookup(productId)
x = (barcode(productId),metric(size))
```

The second version doesn't work that well with list comprehensions, though.

Comment: Please give an example of your desired input and output to clarify what the Haskell `let` construct is doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add a where clause with list comprehension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608238/is-it-possible-to-add-a-where-clause-with-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use a temporary list comprehension

```
[(barcode(productId), metric(size)) for name, size in [lookup(productId)]][0]
```

or, equivalently, a generator expression

```
next((barcode(productId), metric(size)) for name, size in [lookup(productId)])
```

but both of those are pretty horrible.

Another (horrible) method is via a temporary lambda, which you call immediately

```
(lambda (name, size): (barcode(productId), metric(size)))(lookup(productId))
```

---

I think the recommended "Pythonic" way would just be to define a function, like

```
def barcode_metric(productId):
   name, size = lookup(productId)
   return barcode(productId), metric(size)
list2 = [barcode_metric(productId) for productId in list]
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding why you have a one-item list containing only the result of a single call to `lookup`. Won't the first two examples generate a `ValueError`?

Comment: @senderle No, they work. It generates a list containing the tuple `lookup` returns as lone element. It then iterates over that list (so the outer loop only runs once too) to unpack the elements and feed them to the other functions in one fell swoop.

Comment: @delnan, ah, so that is supposed to go inside the outer list comprehension. I had it the other way around. Well, +1 for the function, anyway.

Answer (score 23):

Recent python versions allows multiple for clauses in a generator expression, so you can now do something like:

```
list2 = [ barcode(productID), metric(size)
          for productID in list
          for (name,size) in (lookup(productID),) ]
```

which is similar to what Haskell provides too:

```
list2 = [ (barcode productID, metric size)
        | productID <- list
        , let (name,size) = lookup productID ]
```

and denotationally equivalent to

```
list2 = [ (barcode productID, metric size) 
        | productID <- list
        , (name,size) <- [lookup productID] ]
```

Comment: Using a tuple of length 1 so that `for ... in` is the same as `let .. in`... brilliant!

Comment: I loved your solution but instead of a tuple like `(expr,)` I used a 1-element list like `[expr]` since it didn't have a dangling comma.

Answer (score 12):

There is no such thing. You *could* emulate it the same way `let` is desugared to lambda calculus (`let x = foo in bar` <=> `(\x -> bar) (foo)`).

The most readable alternative depends on the circumstances. For your specific example, I'd choose something like `[barcode(productId), metric(size) for productId, (_, size) in zip(productIds, map(lookup, productIds))]` (really ugly on second thought, it's easier if you don't need `productId` too, then you could use `map`) or an explicit `for` loop (in a generator):

```
def barcodes_and_metrics(productIds):
    for productId in productIds:
        _, size = lookup(productId)
        yield barcode(productId), metric(size)
```

Comment: I'd be worried that doing that with a lambda expression in Python code might have undesired side-effects, such as your door being kicked in by a mob of angry Pythonistas carrying torches and pitchforks.

Comment: @senderle You're right, fixed it now. The list comprehension becomes gets uglier and uglier the more correct it becomes.

Comment: I chose your second suggestion. The third was a bit of an overkill in the actual code and although I like the first from a theoretical standpoint McCann is probably right. Thanks.

Comment: @Perseids Honestly I consider the second line nearly as bad as the first. It's clever and a oneliner, but it's not readable or clear. The third means more lines, but it's still pretty terse if used in multiple places, and really obvious.

Comment: When in Rome, do as the Romans do. Going against expected style and idiom is unwise in most programming languages, doubly so in Python (optional punch line: ...but in perl, it's an art form).

Comment: Well, you're right. It even get's a bit more complicated in the actual code. I'll go with dbaupp suggestion, which fits a bit better than your iterator, as I need that list anyway

Answer (score 9):

The multiple for clauses in b0fh's answer is the style I have personally been using for a while now, as I believe it provides more clarity and doesn't clutter the namespace with temporary functions. However, if speed is an issue, it is important to remember that temporarily constructing a one element list takes notably longer than constructing a one-tuple.

Comparing the speed of the various solutions in this thread, I found that the ugly lambda hack is slowest, followed by the nested generators and then the solution by b0fh. However, these were all surpassed by the one-tuple winner:

```
list2 = [ barcode(productID), metric(size)
          for productID in list
          for (_, size) in (lookup(productID),) ]
```

This may not be so relevant to the OP's question, but there are other cases where clarity can be greatly enhanced and speed gained in cases where one might wish to use a list comprehension, by using one-tuples instead of lists for dummy iterators.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3.8, assignment expressions using the `:=` operator were added: [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

This can be used somewhat like `let` in Haskell, although iterable unpacking is not supported.

```
list2 = [
    (lookup_result := lookup(productId), # store tuple since iterable unpacking isn't supported
     name := lookup_result[0], # manually unpack tuple
     size := lookup_result[1],
     (barcode(productId), metric(size)))[-1] # put result as the last item in the tuple, then extract on the result using the (...)[-1]
    for productId in list1
]
```

Note that this is scoped like a normal Python assignment, e.g. if used inside a function, the variables bound will be accessible throughout the entire function, not just in the expression.

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked for best readability you could consider the lambda-option but with a small twist: initialise the arguments. Here are various options I use myself, starting with the first I tried and ending with the one I use most now.

Suppose we have a function (not shown) which gets `data_structure` as argument, and you need to get `x` from it repeatedly.

First try (as per 2012 answer from huon):

```
(lambda x:
    x * x + 42 * x)
  (data_structure['a']['b'])
```

With multiple symbols this becomes less readable, so next I tried:

```
(lambda x, y:
    x * x + 42 * x + y)
  (x = data_structure['a']['b'],
   y = 16)
```

That is still not very readable as it repeats the symbolic names. So then I tried:

```
(lambda x = data_structure['a']['b'],
        y = 16:
  x * x + 42 * x + y)()
```

This almost reads as an 'let' expression. The positioning and formatting of the assignments is yours of course.

This idiom is easily recognised by the starting '(' and the ending '()'.

In functional expressions (also in Python), many parenthesis tend to pile up at the end. The odd one out '(' is easily spotted.

Comment: I like your third version a lot. As you say, it even looks like a `let` expression!

Answer (score 4):

Only guessing at what Haskell does, here's the alternative. It uses what's known in Python as "list comprehension".

```
[barcode(productId), metric(size)
    for (productId, (name, size)) in [
        (productId, lookup(productId)) for productId in list_]
]
```

You could include the use of `lambda:`, as others have suggested.

Comment: Incidentally--if memory serves me, list comprehensions in Python were largely inspired by Haskell's. Syntactic minutia and weird Haskell compiler extensions aside, they're quite similar. Haskell has been using syntactic whitespace for longer, too. ;]

Comment: Are you saying that python is doing with Haskell what Java was meant to do (and perhaps did) with Lisp—that is, bring nice stuff from function-land into object-land? :)

Answer (score 4):

```
class let:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.x = var

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.x

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass

with let(os.path) as p:
    print(p)
```

But this is effectively the same as `p = os.path` as `p`'s scope is not confined to the with block. To achieve that, you'd need

```
class let:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.value = var
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        del var.value
        var.value = None

with let(os.path) as var:
    print(var.value)  # same as print(os.path)
print(var.value)  # same as print(None)
```

Here `var.value` will be `None` outside of the with block, but `os.path` within it.

Answer (score 3):

To get something vaguely comparable, you'll either need to do two comprehensions or maps, or define a new function. One approach that hasn't been suggested yet is to break it up into two lines like so. I believe this is somewhat readable; though probably defining your own function is the right way to go:

```
pids_names_sizes = (pid, lookup(pid) for pid in list1)
list2 = [(barcode(pid), metric(size)) for pid, (name, size) in pids_names_sizes]
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you can simply write this as:

```
list2 = [(barcode(pid), metric(lookup(pid)[1]))
         for pid in list]
```

You could define `LET` yourself to get:

```
list2 = [LET(('size', lookup(pid)[1]),
             lambda o: (barcode(pid), metric(o.size)))
         for pid in list]
```

or even:

```
list2 = map(lambda pid: LET(('name_size', lookup(pid),
                             'size', lambda o: o.name_size[1]),
                            lambda o: (barcode(pid), metric(o.size))),
            list)
```

as follows:

```
import types

def _obj():
  return lambda: None

def LET(bindings, body, env=None):
  '''Introduce local bindings.
  ex: LET(('a', 1,
           'b', 2),
          lambda o: [o.a, o.b])
  gives: [1, 2]

  Bindings down the chain can depend on
  the ones above them through a lambda.
  ex: LET(('a', 1,
           'b', lambda o: o.a + 1),
          lambda o: o.b)
  gives: 2
  '''
  if len(bindings) == 0:
    return body(env)

  env = env or _obj()
  k, v = bindings[:2]
  if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
    v = v(env)

  setattr(env, k, v)
  return LET(bindings[2:], body, env)
```