# Use an expression twice in one line - as a condition AND for string formatting?

Tags: python, lambda, formatting, conditional-statements

I find that in lots of different projects I'm writing a lot of code where I need to evaluate a (moderately complex, possibly costly-to-evaluate) expression and then do something with it (e.g. use it for string formatting), but only if the expression is True/non-None.

For example in lots of places I end up doing something like the following:

```
result += '%s '%( <complexExpressionForGettingX> ) if <complexExpressionForGettingX> else ''
```

... which I guess is basically a special-case of the more general problem of wanting to return some function of an expression, but only if that expression is True, i.e.:

```
f( e() ) if e() else somedefault
```

but without re-typing the expression (or re-evaluating it, in case it's a costly function call).

Obviously the required logic can be achieved easily enough in various long-winded ways (e.g. by splitting the expression into multiple statements and assigning the expression to a temporary variable), but that's a bit grungy and since this seems like quite a generic problem, and since python is pretty cool (especially for functional stuff) I wondered if there's a nice, elegant, concise way to do it?

My current best options are either defining a short-lived lambda to take care of it (better than multiple statements, but a bit hard to read):

```
(lambda e: '%s ' % e if e else '')( <complexExpressionForGettingX> )
```

or writing my own utility function like:

```
def conditional(expr, formatStringIfTrue, default='')
```

... but since I'm doing this in lots of different code-bases I'd much rather use a built-in library function or some clever python syntax if such a thing exists

Comment: How about `result += '%s '%( <complexExpressionForGettingX> or '')`?

Comment: @wim - returns `' '` for negative expression. OP wants `''`

Comment: Ah, you're right, whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hearing the responses (thanks guys!) I'm now convinced there's no way to achieve what I want in Python without defining a new function (or lambda function) since that's the only way to introduce a new scope.

For best clarity I decided this needed to be implemented as a reusable function (not lambda) so for the benefit of others, I thought I'd share the function I finally came up with - which is flexible enough to cope with multiple additional format string arguments (in addition to the main argument used to decide whether it's to do the formatting at all); it also comes with pythondoc to show correctness and illustrate usage (if you're not sure how the **kwargs thing works just ignore it, it's just an implementation detail and was the only way I could see to implement an optional defaultValue= kwarg following the variable list of format string arguments).

```
def condFormat(formatIfTrue, expr, *otherFormatArgs, **kwargs):
""" Helper for creating returning the result of string.format() on a 
specified expression if the expressions's bool(expr) is True 
(i.e. it's not None, an empty list  or an empty string or the number zero), 
or return a default string (typically '') if not. 

For more complicated cases where the operation on expr is more complicated 
than a format string, or where a different condition is required, use:
(lambda e=myexpr: '' if not e else '%s ' % e)

formatIfTrue -- a format string suitable for use with string.format(), e.g. 
    "{}, {}" or "{1}, {0:d}". 
expr -- the expression to evaluate. May be of any type. 
defaultValue -- set this keyword arg to override

>>> 'x' + condFormat(', {}.', 'foobar')
'x, foobar.'

>>> 'x' + condFormat(', {}.', [])
'x'

>>> condFormat('{}; {}', 123, 456, defaultValue=None)
'123; 456'

>>> condFormat('{0:,d}; {2:d}; {1:d}', 12345, 678, 9, defaultValue=None)
'12,345; 9; 678'

>>> condFormat('{}; {}; {}', 0, 678, 9, defaultValue=None) == None
True

"""
defaultValue = kwargs.pop('defaultValue','')
assert not kwargs, 'unexpected kwargs: %s'%kwargs
if not bool(expr): return defaultValue

if otherFormatArgs:
    return formatIfTrue.format( *((expr,)+otherFormatArgs) )
else:
    return formatIfTrue.format(expr)
```

Answer (score 8):

I like one-liners, definitely. But sometimes they are the wrong solution.

In professional software development, if the team size is > 2, you spent more time on understanding code someone else wrote than on writing new code. The one-liners presented here are definitely confusing, so just do two lines (even though you mentioned multiple statements in your post):

```
X = <complexExpressionForGettingX>
result += '%s '% X  if X else ''
```

This is clear, concise, and everybody immediately understands what's going on here.

Comment: -1: hmmm yes sometimes they're the wrong thing, but other times (specially when you need to do it many times within a function) it's a lot clearer to do stuff in a single expression than to introduce a spurious short-term variable (e.g. X) into the namespace and take up two lines of the source file to do a single operation (even imho for 'professional software development'!) - I think in my case that approach would impede readability, especially by comparison to defining a helper function to tackle this common case. Also I did make clear in my question that I'd considered this approach.

Comment: Perhaps a meaningful variable name would improve this strategy.  In that case, the extra line is almost a comment.

Comment: Yes, you're definitely right! I chose X only because of the choice of OP, and because of a lack of context what X could be.
Sometimes I even define variable for a number like `1`, just for reasons of documentation, e.g., `correction_for_offset = 1`. This makes code much easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 4):

Python doesn't have expression scope ([Is there a Python equivalent of the Haskell 'let'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219465/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-haskell-let)), presumably because the abuses and confusion of the syntax outweigh the advantages.

If you absolutely have to use an expression scope, the least worst option is to abuse a generator comprehension:

```
result += next('%s '%(e) if e else '' for e in (<complexExpressionForGettingX>,))
```

Comment: +1. While I think that it is more complex than the lambda stuff provided by the OP, it is a valid and nice alternative worth considering in more complex circumstances.

Comment: -1: This is better than thinking up a name for the intermediate result?  This is confusing and twisty, and requires you to think up a name anyway.  Just split it into two statements.

Comment: @NedBatchelder adding a statement doesn't always make sense e.g. if the scoped expression is itself embedded in a conditional.  Of course in that case refactoring is likely to be a good idea anyway.

Comment: although I'm not convinced this use of comprehensions is as clear as my original lambda expression, +1 for the important and useful observation that python doesn't have expression-level scope (only classes and functions define scope, plus stuff like lambdas/comprehensions that is kindof a function behind the scenes). This explains why in Python there's no just no way to do what I want other than defining a function (or lambda function).

Answer (score 3):

You could define a conditional formatting function once, and use it repeatedly:

```
def cond_format(expr, form, alt):
    if expr:
        return form % expr
    else:
        return alt
```

Usage:

```
result += cond_format(<costly_expression>, '%s ', '')
```

Comment: yep true, I'll give you +1 for writing it out, though I did suggest this possible approach already in my question. I also added a more complete and fully-featured condFormat method as my answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to do this *repeatedly* to build up a string. With a more global view, you might find that `filter` (or `itertools.ifilter`) does what you want to the collection of values.

You'll wind up with something like this:

```
' '.join(map(str, filter(None, <iterable of <complexExpressionForGettingX>>)))
```

Using `None` as the first argument for `filter` indicates to accept any true value. As a concrete example with a simple expression:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str, filter(None, range(-3, 3))))
'-3 -2 -1 1 2'
```

Depending on how you're calculating the values, it may be that an equivalent list or generator comprehension would be more readable.