# better code structure with for, if, and set in python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, set

My code is as follows. It loops through blobs which is set of frozenset and check if each blob intersects with mapped which is a set. If a blob does intersects with mapped and also satisfies the condition of being terminal, then add the intersection set to the result.

```
result = set()
for b in blobs:                                                   
    mapped_b = b & mapped                                                 
    if mapped_b and _is_terminal(mapped_b):                          
        result.add(mapped_b)
```

Can this logic be written in a better way? I was thinking of list comprehension, but since mapped_b is formed on the go, it seems I have to make it multiple times which is wasteful.

```
[result.add(b&mapped) for b in blobs if b&mapped and _is_terminal(b&mapped)]
```

Also is it worth the trouble to use `filter` for the `if` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is [no such thing as a `let` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219465/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-the-haskell-let) (like for instance in Haskell) that would allow to temporary store the `mapped_b` result.

You can however use `map` or a generator to store the intermediate result. Like:

```
result = {mapped_b for mapped_b in map(lambda b:b&mapped,blobs) if mapped_b and _is_terminal(mapped_b)}
```

So `map(lambda b:b&mapped,blobs)` will generate the `mapped_b` items (in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) one at a time, in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) with a temprorary list).

Or you can use a generator yourself:

```
result = {mapped_b for mapped_b in (b&mapped for b in blobs) if mapped_b and _is_terminal(mapped_b)}
```

Note that we here use ***set*** comprehension, **not list** comprehension. In the original code fragment, you also construct a `set`.

**EDIT**:

based on your comment, you can indeed omit the `if` part by using a `filter` like:

```
result = set(filter(lambda b: b and _is_terminal(b),(b&mapped for b in blobs)))
```

This is semantically equivalent. Whether one is preferred over the other is usually an aspect of taste. Here the two are easily interchangeable.

Comment: What do you think about `result=set(filter(lambda b: if b and _is_terminal(b), (b&mapped for b in blobs)))`? Is it bad code?

Comment: not per se, but my experience is that *set comprehension* is usually more efficient (and more elegant as well). Afaik `filter` will not boost the process (much). But it will have semantically the same result.

Comment: @nos: note that you should drop the `if` in the `lambda` of the `filter`.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. Thank you very much for all the information.